# How do I fetch the date on click using embed bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i am using the embedded bootstrap calendar and want the user to click on a day to display data underneath after the ajax event will go to url.

I now get the click event to happen using the `.on('changeDate', getDate);` addition, I can see it is showing in the POST that this data is transmitted, but in my Codeigniter i can't fetch this value. My variable is empty.

Below is my code, but check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt81efz7/1/) it shows better.

> SOLVED, it forgot the `POST` method in Codeigniter, had used `GET`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // below to initialise the embedded datepicker calendar
  $('#calendar').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    todayBtn: true,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  }).on('changeDate', getDate);

  // below is to get the click event for the calendar "not working"
  function getDate() {
    var grpcalendar = $('#calendar').datepicker('getFormattedDate');

    $.ajax({
      url: "./Controller/send_my_date_here",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        grp_caldate: grpcalendar
      },
      success: function(response) {}
    });
    // below some tables got reload for content refresh after date select
    $('#Table1').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    $('#Table2').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    $('#Table3').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    $('#Table4').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);
    $('#Table5').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried with input just try this link http://jsfiddle.net/klenwell/LcqM7/

Comment: It is ok, i got it done. The Codeigniter was set to `GET` instead `POST` therefore it couldn't get the value. But thanks.